# how to read user ROLES using XSJS?

Tags: hana

​I would like to know what the session user has access to. For example if user X has access to a particular database or a set of tables. When looking into HANA I see that I have the PUBLIC role that allows me to see the database, how can I pull this information using XSJS so I can perform logic based on those roles? 
I've used $.session.hasSystemPrivilege("PRIV");  but this is different than checking roles. I tried testing for "INSERT" for inserting into the database which returned false. I know that I can write to the tables. Looking in to the HANA, the system privileges tab is empty for me.

Could someone give me some guidance here?

Answer (score 0):

Create your analytic/calculation view on top of SYS.GRANTED_ROLES or GRANTED_PRIVILEGES.
Expose your view as OData service and access this service in XSJS.